# Can Battlecries be applied to the minion you just played?

Tags: hearthstone

Can Battlecries that get applied to minions be applied to the minion you just played?  , e.g can the [Dark Iron Dwarf](http://www.hearthhead.com/card=348/dark-iron-dwarf) give itself +2 Attack until the end of the turn?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot use a battlecry on the minion that has it, unless it *specifically says* it does something to itself or can be self-targeted.

Comment: Just curious, what are some examples where cards do specifically apply a Battlecry to itself?

Comment: @dlanod I think Injured Blademaster is one, can't check right now.

Comment: Injured Blademaster's battlecry is "Deal 4 damage to HIMSELF". You can't choose any other targets.

Comment: More generally, minions don't exist on the board until played, and you can't target something not on the board. The flow is: Pick Targets -> Play Minion -> Resolve Battlecry.